# Import error : cannot import name 'DocumentAnalysisClient' from 'azure.ai.formrecognizer'

Tags: azure, importerror, azure-form-recognizer

When I am running following code `from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient` getting error as Import error : cannot import name 'DocumentAnalysisClient' from 'azure.ai.formrecognizer'

I am using azure form recongizer service and trying to import DocumentAnalyseClient.I need to resolve the error. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Make sure you're using the ***latest stable pip version of
> azure-ai-formrecognizer which is version 3.2.1*** as per this
> [**Link1**](https://pypi.org/project/azure-ai-formrecognizer/). And ***DocumentAnalysisClient was introduced in pip version  3.2.0b1 as mentioned in this [**Link2**](https://pypi.org/project/azure-ai-formrecognizer/3.2.0b1/). So make sure your azure-ai-formrecognizer  version is 3.2.0b1 or above.***

I installed the latest version of  azure-ai-formrecognizer and did not receive any import error with DocumentAnalysisClient, Refer below:-

> ```py
> pip install azure-ai-formrecognizer==3.2.0 OR 
> pip install azure-ai-formrecognizer
> ```

[image]

[image]

**Code:-**

> I have referred the below code from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=windows) and followed the same document.
>
> Copied my API Key and endpoint from here:-

[image]

I have set the key and endpoint as Environment variable in my terminal like below:-

> ```
> setx FR_KEY <Key>
> setx FR_ENDPOINT <endpoint>
> ```

[image]

Close the Terminal and VS Code and open again for above variables to populate. Now, Run the code below:-

While running the code below which I referred from this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/how-to-guides/use-sdk-rest-api?view=form-recog-3.0.0&pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=windows), I did not receive any Import error:-

> ```py
> import os 
> from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
> from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
>
> # use your `key` and `endpoint` environment variables key = os.environ.get('FR_KEY') endpoint = os.environ.get('FR_ENDPOINT')
>
> # formatting function def format_polygon(polygon):
>     if not polygon:
>         return "N/A"
>     return ", ".join(["[{}, {}]".format(p.x, p.y) for p in polygon])
>
>
> def analyze_read():
>     # sample form document
>     formUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-REST-api-samples/master/curl/form-recognizer/rest-api/read.png"
>
>     document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
>         endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(key)
>     )
>
>     poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url(
>         "prebuilt-read", formUrl
>     )
>     result = poller.result()
>
>     print("Document contains content: ", result.content)
>
>     for idx, style in enumerate(result.styles):
>         print(
>             "Document contains {} content".format(
>                 "handwritten" if style.is_handwritten else "no handwritten"
>             )
>         )
>
>     for page in result.pages:
>         print("----Analyzing Read from page #{}----".format(page.page_number))
>         print(
>             "Page has width: {} and height: {}, measured with unit: {}".format(
>                 page.width, page.height, page.unit
>             )
>         )
>
>         for line_idx, line in enumerate(page.lines):
>             print(
>                 "...Line # {} has text content '{}' within bounding box '{}'".format(
>                     line_idx,
>                     line.content,
>                     format_polygon(line.polygon),
>                 )
>             )
>
>         for word in page.words:
>             print(
>                 "...Word '{}' has a confidence of {}".format(
>                     word.content, word.confidence
>                 )
>             )
>
>     print("----------------------------------------")
>
>
> if __name__ == "__main__":
>     analyze_read()
> ```

**Output:-**
[image]

**Document Analyzed successfully:-**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using  3.2.0  form recognizer version. Still i am getting same error.
ImportError: cannot import name 'DocumentAnalysisClient' from 'azure.ai.formrecognizer' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\azure\ai\formrecognizer\__init__.py)

Comment: Okay, Try to change your Python interpreter to another Python version, when I did pip install azure-ai-formrecognizer It did not reflect in my Python interpreter 3.11 then I changed the interpretor in my VS Code to python 3.10 and the import error was resolved

Comment: I uninstalled azure form recognizer package and installed again. Now I am not getting any error. Thank you so much for your help.